# Why do I get an error in Laravel when session has timed out and I try to log out beyond that time

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am running Laravel 6 on Homestead. I have seen similar errors here but none specific to my situation.

- If I log in, that's fine.
- If I log out straight away, that fine too.
- If I leave the screen to timeout beyond the session_lifetime set in .env, it wont log out without this error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() 
must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given, 
called in /home/vagrant/code/MySite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 60
```

I'm learning Laravel and coming from vanilla php, I haven't a clue where to start looking. Thanks in advance.

I dont have access to login routes am using Auth:routes() in web.php. I think i may have solved the problem by overriding logout(). Seems a bit to simplistic. Wonder if this is secure?

```
    public function logout(Request $request){
    Auth::logout();
    return  redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Edit, sorry that does not solve my problem. It works within active session time but outside that i have same problem

Unfortunately, that does not work for me. I see the logic why it should but same error shows. As an experiment, I just returned "hello world" on its own in logout method and sure enough it just shows up on logout page no errors. But if I do this I get the same error as above (no logout functions just a rtn view)

```
    public function logout(Request $request){
      //if (Auth::check()) {
      //  Auth::logout();
      //}
      //return  redirect()->route('home');
      //$request->session()->flush();
      return view('front.pages.aboutus');
      //return  "hello world";
    }
```

As you can see I have been experimenting with flush() too but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses session cookies. If you give that cookie a lifetime, the browser will delete that cookie as soon as the lifetime is expired. Therefore on your Laravel project you can no longer log out the user by removing the cookie manually since the cookie is already gone.

**EDIT to make my answer correspond to the changed details in the question:**
Two possible solutions: If you can change the routes, make your logout route only available to logged in users. If they're already logged out, just redirect to the homepage. (See [Route middlewares in Laravel Authentication Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes))

As a more direct approach if you can't/don't want to manipulate your routes, you can just perform an `Auth::check()` in your logout function.
If `Auth::check()` returns true, the user is logged in and you need to log them out first:

```
    public function logout(Request $request){
      if (Auth::check()) {
        Auth::logout();
      }
      return  redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

(see Laravel Docs for [Retrieving The Authenticated User](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Comment: Thanks Mastacheata. I thought Laravel would cover this scenario. Where in the code do you think I could check if cookie exists when logout is clicked and redirect to login page

Comment: Mind showing where your code errors ou?

You can only check if a key/variable exists in a session, but not really determine if a session itself is currently active/exists using Laravel.

You could probably mark your logout route as "authenticated only" and redirect to the front page or wherever your logout leads otherwise.

Comment: Edited my answer to correspond to your edit  and show both a solution that will solve your immediate problem as well as point you at how to do it "the right way" - Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok eventually found the problem. I had a string returned in app/exceptions handler method when i was trying to debug a 419 problem and forgot to change it back

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
      if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
          return redirect()->route('login'); // <- the solution
          //return "hello world";// <- the problem
      }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

I think it is a good solution to have the user go somewhere useful after clicking logout regardless of whether the actual session has timed out or not. A 419? pretty useless. At least the above solution sends them somewhere. It could probably be a different route choice from mine here also I would imagine. Thanks Mastacheata for your help along the way.